# Role of $K$ be a compact space in showing that $L$ is positive.

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612699/l-in-x-and-l-l-textbf1-if-and-only-if-l-is-a-positive-operat) question. I am going to just copy it here again.

Ley $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $X = C(K)$ be the space of continuous functions defined on $K$ with values in $\mathbb{K}$ alongside the supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$. Show that $L \in X^*$ and $\|L\| = L(\textbf{1})$, if and only if $L$ is a positive operator, that is, $L(f) \geq 0$ when $f \geq 0$.
By $\textbf{1} \in X$ we are refering to the constant function $1$.

The proof provided by a user is the following:

Let $a$ be a positive element such that $I(a)<0$. For a small enough $\beta$, $\|1-\beta a\|< 1$, but we have $I(1-\beta a)=I(1)-\beta I(a)>I(1)=\|I\|\geq \|I\| \|1-\beta a\|$, hence we get a contradiction, then $I$ is positive.

I understand that proof, but there is one piece missing. The fact that $K$ was a compact Hausdorff space was never used. My question is then, how does that fact play in?

I think it plays in, in that it gives boundedness of $I$, namely, since $L\in X^*$, then $L<\infty$. But I am not sure of that. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: If $K$ is not compact then the sup norm on $C(K)$ is not defined and the question does not even make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using it explicitly to get that $\|1-\beta a\|$ is *strictly* smaller than $1$. Say $K=\mathbb{R}$ (and we're considering the set of *bounded* continuous functions on $K$, so that the norm makes sense) and $a(x)=\exp(-|x|)$, then $\|1-\beta a\|\geq 1-\lim_{x\to \infty}a(x)=1$, so that part of the argument collapses, even though $a$ is strictly positive.

Comment: Just to check for understanding: if $K$ is not compact, then I can have functions that vanish at infinity, hence $||1-\beta a|| <1$ does not hold anymore, just like the example you showed. On the other hand, if $K$ is compact then $||1-\beta a||\geq 1 -\epsilon$, which is in other words is $||1-\beta a||<1$. So, is that reasoning correct?

Comment: If $K$ is compact, then we pick $\beta$ such that $\|\beta a\|\leq 1$ (that's certainly possible even in the non-compact setting). In this case, $1-\beta a$ assumes its supremum somewhere, say at $x_0$, but by assumption, $0 <\beta a(x_0)\leq 1$, which gives you your $\varepsilon$.